# androidのwifi経由でのadbについて

Tags: android

下記コマンドを行うとwifi経由でadbコマンドが使用できる様になりますが
wifiのInterface(wlan0)にのみbindされるのでしょうか？
wifi以外のsim経由や、VPNなどのinterfaceから接続される事はありますか？

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.xx.xx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPNやglobal ip経由でも接続可能です。
一般的な携帯ですとglobalに出ているわけではないので接続できないです。

接続確認が出るので勝手に接続される事はないと思います。